# Möbius Strip + Möbius Strip = Klein Bottle, What about Klein Bottle + Klein Bottle =?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, mobius-band, klein-bottle

We know that 2 Möbius-Strips can be joined edge-wise to eliminate that edge producing 0 Edge topological structure.

**ML (Möbius Left) + MR (Möbius Right) = KOJ (Simple "inverted sock" Klein Bottle)**

**ML + ML = K8L-O (Left-handed figure-8 Klein bottle)**

**MR + MR = K8R-O (Right-handed figure-8 Klein bottle)**

Now I have "possibly naive" questions. Edges can be eliminated by joining them, can this analogy be used for joining surfaces. That is going by normal imagination overlapping 2 surface leads to decrease in number of total surface. So my questions -

**So are there any topological structures with "zero" surfaces.**

**Can this be achieved by joining opposite/ similar chiral/ non-chiral Klein bottles.**

**What will be properties of such topological structure.**

Please note that I have by no means deep understanding of topology and only have superficial knowledge that I gained by browsing through some videos or relatively simple papers. So please be lenient if my questions are not well formed.

Comment: One way to generalize the idea of "joining two Möbius strips along their boundaries" is as follows: if $M$ and $N$ are two $n$-dimensional manifolds and if there is a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon \partial M \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \partial N$ between their boundaries, you can form the quotient space $M\cup_\varphi N$ where $x\in \partial M$ is identified with $\varphi(x)\in \partial N$, and this will be an $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. You could compute the homology of such a space from $H_*(M)$, $H_*(N)$, and $H_*(\partial M)$ using Meyer-Vietoris.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "'zero' surfaces"? the number of surfaces or some topological invariant is equal to zero? 2. You can, obviously, eliminate 2-dimensional surfaces by joining them together (identifying them). e.g. You can join the boundary of an 3 dimensioanl $\partial$-manifold to eliminate it, just like what you did with the mobius strip. Analogously, you could apply the similar method to any $\partial-$manifold ($n$-manifold with boundary) which will help you get rid of the $(n-1)$- boundary. Details can be found in William's comment.

Comment: Thanks, William and Kevin for your replies. Really appreciate the incite. I think above comments answer my question. Just curious if you know specifics in case ∂ -manifold is Klein bottle and we join 2 such manifolds. Asking this because I was not able to imagine manifold without surface and was curious about it, but did not have sufficient background knowledge in topology.

Comment: @DhruvBansal $\partial$-manifold means manifold with boundary. However, the klein bottle, as a kind of closed manifolds, has empty boundary and hence not a $\partial$-manifold. For this, I think you may need to read some intro to topological manifold. For your curiosity, consider $S^1\times S^1$ which is the 2-torus, its boundary should be some edges if any, but we can see that any point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $B^2$ which means there is no boundary of $T^2$. Similarly, this might happen in 3-dimensional cases by joining their 2-dim boundary.

Comment: For $X$ to be a 3 dimensional $\partial$-manifold,  it has to satisfy the condition that any point has at least a neighbothood homeomorphic to open subsets of $\Bbb{H}^3=\{(x,y,z)|z\ge0\}$. Besides, every point that is to be mapped to $\partial\Bbb{H}^3$, is a boundary point in 3-d case. An obvious example is to take two solid torus $X=S^1\times D^2=Y$ and define a attaching homeomorphism $\phi:\partial X\to \partial Y$ then take the adjunction space $X\cup_{\phi}Y=(X\sqcup Y)/(x\sim\phi(x))$. Then, the $\partial S^1\times D^2 = T^2$ is eliminated and hence we obtained a closed manifold.

Comment: @DhruvBansal In your situation (klein bottle), define $\psi:\partial K_1\to \partial K_2$ to be a homeomorphism between the boundaries of two klein bottles. Then, $K_1\cup_{\psi}K_2$ doesn't change anything because any point $x\in K_1\cup_{\psi}K_2$ still admits a euclidean neighborhood of dimension 2. Thus, you can't say the resulting space of joining two klein bottles together has zero surfaces...

Comment: @Kevin.S Thank you very much for the deep dive.

Comment: @Kevin.S  How did you reach this conclusion "1∪2 doesn't change anything because any point ∈1∪2 still admits a euclidean neighbourhood of dimension 2." Does this hold for opposite chiral Klein Bottles as well mentioned in my original question.